# Exception in thread main playn

Tags: playn

I am trying to run a playn project but I am getting the following exception:

```
[java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Function is not supported
[java]     at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkFunctionAddress(BufferChecks.java:58)
[java]     at org.lwjgl.opengl.EXTFramebufferObject.glBindFramebufferEXT(EXebufferObject.java:199)
[java]     at playn.java.JavaGLContext.bindFramebufferImpl(JavaGLContext.java:150)
[java]     at playn.core.gl.GLContext.viewWasResized(GLContext.java:250)
[java]     at playn.java.JavaGLContext.initGL(JavaGLContext.java:174)
[java]     at playn.java.JavaGraphics.init(JavaGraphics.java:155)
[java]     at playn.java.JavaPlatform.run(JavaPlatform.java:218)
[java]     at playn.core.PlayN.run(PlayN.java:37)
[java]     at com.domain.project.java.GameLoopJava.main(GameLoopJava.java:13)
```

This is a custom project. I have run the command "mvn test" and got the above. Could someone please tell me what this means?

Thank you!

Comment: put the code here which is throwing exception.

Comment: This is the code with the exception:
`package com.domain.project.java;

import playn.core.PlayN;
import playn.java.JavaPlatform;

import com.domain.project.core.GameLoop;

public class GameLoopJava {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JavaPlatform platform = JavaPlatform.register();
    platform.assets().setPathPrefix("com/domain/project/resources");
    PlayN.run(new GameLoop());
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using playn1.3 you need the lwjgl libraries on your build path, also your graphics card must support openGL 2.0.

Comment: My graphics card can support up to OpenGL 1.4 only, with the latest driver. Thank you!

Comment: Same issue. Does that mean we cannot use PlayN on any system with OpenGL less than 2.0 ?? ( PlayN is now in 1.5 )